# CSS stretch elements to fit container height

Tags: css, stretching

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zP97v/) - how to stretch `li` elements to parent container height, so they fit all in `ul` with appropriate height?
I need smth like that:

[image: expected result]

Comment: you want to get ul height and fetch all ul?

Comment: Does it have to be a css only solution or can js/jquery be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul { display: table;}
li { display: table-row;}
```

Comment: could you please edit http://jsfiddle.net/zP97v/ to demonstrate how it works with your solution regarding to provided example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, almost as should be. But, changing width for ul make effect for li also, and second - margin doesn't works for li

Comment: How margin doesn't work for li? I did not entirely changed the width for ul, that is a min-width.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv can you tell me the context in witch you wish to use this list, so I can find a solution and help you furthermore? A printscreen will work.

Comment: This only seems to work if a fixed height is given to the UL.

Answer (score 0):

Include one line inside the block of stylesheets for li

```
height: 25%;
```

Comment: number of elements will be random